# Django : Starts with directly accessing foreign key value

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models that look like the following below

```
class DjImagingImage(models.Model):
    img_documentnbr = models.ForeignKey('Tblinvrev', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='IMG_DocumentNbr', max_length=200, to_field='drawingid', related_name='drawing_meta') 


class Tblinvrev(models.Model):
    """
    Table for keeping track of Index Images and the most recent metadata
    """
    rectype = models.CharField(db_column='RecType', max_length=1)  # Field name made lowercase.
    drawingid = models.CharField(db_column='DrawingID', primary_key=True, max_length=20)
```

Sometimes images are not entered into TblInvrev

Now I want to search without using the relationship as I might be missing records if I do so

```
DjImagingImage.objects.filter(img_documentnbr_id__startswith='cow') # Does not work. I use _id to access the foreign key value directly

DjImagingImage.objects.filter(img_documentnbr__drawingid__startswith='cow') # Works but items not indexed in tblinvrev will not show
```

How can I use the foreign key value in DjImagingImage to do so without traversing the relationship?

Comment: I assume `Tblinvrev` is the `index` as in your `ForeignKey`?

Comment: you are correct. I made the edit to fix the error.